# Android Studio: Gradle error; A problem occurred evaluating project ':connectivity_plus'

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

As title says, I have encountered the error while working on an android project for college of mine.
The entire error says this following:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\william\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\connectivity_plus-4.0.1\android\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':connectivity_plus'.
> No signature of method: build_bou4ub0wbhz1n3u4prip3694v.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_bou4ub0wbhz1n3u4prip3694v$_run_closure2) values: [build_bou4ub0wbhz1n3u4prip3694v$_run_closure2@3428450e]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Upon checking the build.gradle file, I don't know what the error is and what should be done. But within it, here's what it have:

```
group 'io.flutter.plugins.connectivity'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    namespace 'dev.fluttercommunity.plus.connectivity'

    compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}
```

As per looking up this error, I haven't seen anyone else encounter that specific error regarding 'connectivity_plus' so I am not sure what to do about it. I'm not really an expert on gradle either since the only programming I have done so far are basic Java, Python and Flutter.

Any suggestions would be helpful to fix this.

By the way, this was done on Gradle 7.4.2, Flutter 3.10.1 and having Java 17

Comment: Read the log. Did you try any of the suggestions?

Comment: @aled I'm not really sure how to do the ones suggested actually so I skipped over it for now.

Comment: That's the first thing you should work on. The issue seems in the code, that you didn't share. Without more details it is not possible to help. Also note that connectivity_plus is the name of your project: `evaluating project ':connectivity_plus'`

Comment: @aled sorry for my inexperience, but I don't think I follow. The error did say that it is from the build.gradle file specified in the android folder, in which the one above is the content of it. However, there is also another build.gradle file in my Android Studio project which I also am not sure what I am looking for to be honest as they have different code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue lies in the `android` block.

The error specifically mentions that there is no signature of the method `android()` that is applicable for the given argument. This typically occurs when there is a mismatch between the Gradle version and the Android Gradle plugin version being used.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Update the Gradle version. In the `build.gradle` file of your project (not the one in the 'connectivity_plus' library), make sure you are using a compatible Gradle version.
2. Sync your project. After making any changes to the Gradle files, it's important to sync your project with the updated configurations. In Android Studio, you can click on the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button or select "File" -> "Sync Project with Gradle Files" from the menu.

Comment: May I know what is the gradle version. I'm facing same issue .. I'm using gradle-7.2-bin and classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'

Comment: same issue today bad a day . ```distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip``` with ```classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'``` and i use ```export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home"```